Manage different version of jemalloc in cmake
I have compiled two versions of jemalloc, a release version and one with profiling enabled(--enable-prof). The version with profiling is configured with a suffix(--suffix="-prof").
As a result, there are two libraries installed in the system:
libjemalloc.so and libjemalloc-prof.so
Can you tell me how to select a particular library in cmake?

Have a CMake option, say ENABLE_JEMALLOC_PROFILING, if the flag is true, then link to jemalloc-prof else link to jemalloc.

@kiner_shah I was so slow this morning. This is really the easiest and best solution. Thank you.

In your CMakeLists.txt, you can add an option to enable profiling and then link to jemalloc-prof if it's enabled, else link to jemalloc. Make sure you are calling find_library or find_package whichever is suitable before linking it. Something like below:
# ...
option(ENABLE_JEMALLOC_PROFILING "Enable profiling for Jemalloc" FALSE)

# ...

if (ENABLE_JEMALLOC_PROFILING)
    find_library(JEMALLOC_PROF jemalloc-prof HINTS PATH_HINT1 PATH_HINT2 REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET PRIVATE jemalloc-prof)
else()
    find_library(JEMALLOC jemalloc HINTS PATH_HINT1 PATH_HINT2 REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET PRIVATE jemalloc)
endif()

